# How to print an abstract data type within in a functor in ocamldebug

Tags: debugging, ocaml, pretty-print

I am struggling with how to install a printer function for a type used inside a functor. The structure looks a little like this:

```
module Input : sig
   type t
   val print fmt arg : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
end

module type INPUT = module type of Input

module F (I:INPUT) : sig
   val foo : I.t -> unit
end
```

Now i want to print the value of type `Input.t` used in `F.foo`. I can successfully install a printer for `Input.t` using `load_printer` and `install_printer Input.print` but it does not recognize that the type is the right one when printing from inside `F (Input)`.

As requested here is a self contained example. It should be built with debugging turned on and then the `.cmo` should be loaded with `load_printer` in the debugger.

```
module type INPUT = sig
  type t
  val print : Format.formatter -> t -> unit
  val to_list : t -> int list
  val of_list :  int list -> t
end

module V1 : INPUT = struct
  type t = int
  let print fmt i = Format.fprintf fmt "%d" i
  let to_list i = [i]
  let of_list = function [i] -> i | _ -> raise @@ Failure ""
end

module V2 : INPUT = struct
  type t = int * int
  let print fmt (i, j) = Format.fprintf fmt "%d, %d" i j
  let to_list (i, j) = [i; j]
  let of_list = function [i; j] -> (i, j) | _ -> raise @@ Failure ""
end

module F (V:INPUT) = struct
  let ssquare v = (V.to_list v)
                |> List.map (fun i -> i * i)
                |> List.fold_left (+) 0
  let print fmt v =
    let open Format in
    print_string "<";
    V.to_list v |> List.iter print_int;
    print_string ">"
end

module F2 = F (V2);;

let v2 = V2.of_list [2;4] in
let _ = Format.fprintf Format.std_formatter "%a\n" F2.print v2 in
let _ = F2.ssquare v2 in
()
```

This program prints the value `v2` just fine. However there are actually two problems when debugging. I can `install_printer V2.print`, but when placing the debugger in the `ssquare` function and invoking `print v2` this does not print it. Furthermore, I don't know how I would even install the `print` defined in the functor.

Comment: This seems like a problem that one would run into often but I only found an old mailing list post about it without an answer?

Comment: not many people use ocamldebug, fyi.

Comment: It would help me focus if you would provide code that actually compiles. I don't want to spend too much time thinking about a different question than you're asking :-) On the other hand, if nobody answered last time, it's likely there's no good answer.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian You can install printers in the OCaml toplevel (not just ocamldebug). I've found it useful in the past; sometimes there's a simple notation for a large value.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield i updated the question (don't know if this sends a notification to commenters automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me there's no way to do what you want. One way to look at this is that ocamldebug matches print functions by *type*. But ocamldebug considers the type of the value `v` that you want to print to be `V.t`, and V is a formal parameter of the functor `F`. There's no way (that I can think of) to make a function that accepts this type. The function `F.print` would seem to be a candidate, but it's not an actual function until you instantiate the functor. And the type accepted by the print function in the instantiated functor is no longer `V.t`.

For example, ocamldebug considers the type accepted by `F2.print` to be `V2.t`:

```
(ocd) print N.F2.print
N.F2.print: 'a -> N.V2.t -> unit = <fun>
```

It would be great if there were ways to do things like this, possibly by enriching the way that ocamldebug chooses the printer for a value. But it also sounds kind of hairy.

(Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but as I said it's telling that this question gets asked but never answered.)

Comment: hm, if that's really impossible it seems to limit the usefulness of ocamldebug. i would expect from a debugger that it can actually show the values in a running program. maybe that's one reason people don't use it more? where can i file a feature request?

Comment: I think you're right about the popularity of ocamldebug. You can file feature requests for OCaml at http://caml.inria.fr/mantis There is at least one request there already for ocamldebug to look inside abstract types. That's one way of looking at the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution. It's a start of a workaround which at least allows printers for types inside a functor output to be loaded. However, the loaded printers cannot actually print anything inside ocamldebug. I think this is because ocamldebug does not recognize equality between the types of the printer functions and the types to be printers. Anyway, here it goes.

Create a new file `debug_printers.ml` where the same functor applications are carried out as in the module in question. Let's say the self-contained file listed above in the question is called `vsource.ml`. Then `debug_printers` should contain

```
open Vsource
module F2 = F (V2)
let print_f2 = F2.print
```

Then compile this as `debug_printers.d.cmo` and load it in `ocamldebug` by `load_printer "debug_printers.d.cmo"`. Finally, install the print function by `install_printer print_f2`. This succeeds in loading the function, which has the correct type; however the correctness does not get recognized, so printing still fails.